# I have a container of html, it has absolute positioning, but i want to make it relative to the wrapping div's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jsfiddle of the content:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallenreaper/jv7Zr/

The issue is that i can do the following:

```
$("*").each(function(){
    if( $(this).css("position") == 'absolute'){
        $(this).css("position","");
    }
});
$("div.container").css("position", "absolute");
```

Everything will render as it should...  but it doesnt mean that i can wrap the content and move it.

My goal is to copy that content block and put it into a table in a repeatable fashion but the absolute positioning doesnt allow it.

If i replace the last line with:

```
$("div.container").css("position","relative");
```

it looks all skewed..

Am i missing something?  I was thinking that everything should be working correctly.

Comment: Dude... no. How could you suppose we're going to debug that pile of HTML? Indent it and separate the CSS. Also, use CSS whenever possible (no more `width` and `height` attributes, and so on).

Comment: Where is this div supposed to be positioned relative to it's container?   Dead center, top left top right etc?  Does the width of it's container have fixed dimensions or is it responsive?

Comment: @MaxArt Thats what i was given as the fetched input from a FORM.  thats what the data would be upon retrieval.  Thats why i didnt want to seperate it.  Though, luckily, JSFIDDLE has a tidy button i can use and it will indent it all for ease of use.

Comment: @Michael That content is going to be put into a div   $("<div>").append($input);   and then that is going to be appended to the table in such a way that it copies the form over and over.  Right now, with absolute, they all sit on top of each other.

Comment: @MaxArt each item has a different style position and is rendered from an automated tool.  Thats why they are inline, because even if i tag all the divs, the css file would be just as big.

Comment: The line you added above is correct for the situation I think.  I imagine that the skewing issue u mentioned is a top: or a left: or both need to be adjusted in someway.

Comment: i tried to adjust it by removeAttr all style tags NOT .container, but that even doesnt do much.  Im not sure if the top, left, or both being an issue is actually an issue.  Is there something wrong with how HTML is printed when nested in such a way?  Margins, padding, and all that stuff?  ALSO:  I according to JSFIDDLE, there are some dead tags that i removed.... thinking that might resolve it, but similarly, doesnt actually work at all.